# How to get Bitly clicks using API v4 with PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, url-shortener

I'm referring this URL for API documentation
https://dev.bitly.com/v4_documentation.html

My Code is:

```
//short URL is bit.ly/2WoKAKu
$url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/2WoKAKu/clicks';
$token = 'my-token';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GETFIELDS, json_encode(['unit'=>'day','units'=>-1])); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$token,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
]);

$arr_result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

But receiving this error:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => FORBIDDEN
)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the following line

`"Authorization: Bearer ".$token,`

with

`"Authorization: ".$token,`

Answer (score -1):

try using the below.

$url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/bit.ly/2WoKAKu/clicks';

**A Bitlink made of the domain and hash**