# How to get a url link for Bitly v4 on PHP?

Tags: php, curl, url-shortener, bit.ly

I tried following the replied guide on this post here [How to shorten URL using PHP Bitly v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681871/how-to-shorten-url-using-php-bitly-v4) but it doesn't really work.

this is my code so far with added variables to match what's on the [bitly API documentaiton](https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference#createBitlink)

```
$long_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732875/how-to-get-bitly-clicks-using-api-v4-with-php';
$group_guid = 'mygroupid';
$domain = 'bit.ly';
$apiv4 = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten';
$genericAccessToken = 'myaccesstoken';

$data = array(
    'long_url' => $long_url,
    'domain' => $domain,
    'group_guid' => $group_guid
);
$payload = json_encode($data);
echo $payload;

$header = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$genericAccessToken,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$ch = curl_init($apiv4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Echoed out the payload but no results being printed
[image: Echoed out the payload]

Comment: add in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it showed me a Curl error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate, is it because I'm using it on localhost and not on a website?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: @CBroe thanks for helping me with the problem, the guide showed me how to fix it, and it is now running properly!